# Best way to construct a GraphQL query string in Python

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to do this (see title), but it's a bit complicated since the string I'm trying to build has to have the following properties:

- mulitiline
- contains curly braces
- I want to inject variables into it

Using a normal `''''''` multiline string makes injecting variables difficult. Using multiple f-strings makes injecting variables easy, but every curly brace, of which there are a lot, has to be doubled. And an `f` has to be prepended to each line. On the other hand, if I try using `format`, it also gets confused by all the curly braces.

Is there a better way that I haven't considered yet?

Comment: Maybe template strings, or a full blown template library? Or write yourself a library to construct your graphql in a functional way, and hide the details.

Comment: I only found this lib https://pypi.org/project/gql-query-builder/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the """ multiline string method. For injecting variables, make sure to use the $ sign while defining the string and use the variables object in the JSON parameter of the requests.post method.

Here is an example. `ContactInput` is one of the types I defined in my GraphQL schema.

```
query = """
  mutation ($input:[ContactInput!]!) {
    AddContacts(contacts: $input) {
      user_id
    }
  }
"""
variables = {'input': my_arrofcontacts}
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query , 'variables': variables})
```

Comment: How can syntax highlighting be applied to this multiline string?

Comment: It does not work In my case, (__python 3.8__).
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69235010/how-to-pass-a-variable-as-a-value-in-json) is the solution by [@chris-lindseth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16856522/chris-lindseth).
With string format like as,
Just use multiline string (""") with **f** prefix and for variable use '{_variable_}'.
for brace ('_{_', '_}_') use double for that like as ('_{{_', '_}}_')

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following package [graphql-query](https://pypi.org/project/graphql-query/)

For example, for the query

```graphql
{
  leftComparison: hero(episode: EMPIRE) {
    ...comparisonFields
  }
  rightComparison: hero(episode: JEDI) {
    ...comparisonFields
  }
}

fragment comparisonFields on Character {
  name
  appearsIn
  friends {
    name
  }
}
```

we have the following code

```py
from graphql_query import Argument, Operation, Query, Fragment, Field

comparisonFields = Fragment(
    name="comparisonFields",
    type="Character",
    fields=["name", "appearsIn", Field(name="friends", fields=["name"])]
)

leftComparison = Query(
    name="hero",
    alias="leftComparison",
    arguments=[Argument(name="episode", value="EMPIRE")],
    fields=[comparisonFields]
)

rightComparison = Query(
    name="hero",
    alias="rightComparison",
    arguments=[Argument(name="episode", value="JEDI")],
    fields=[comparisonFields]
)

operation = Operation(
    type="query",
    queries=[leftComparison, rightComparison],
    fragments=[comparisonFields]
)
print(operation.render())
# query {
#   leftComparison: hero(
#     episode: EMPIRE
#   ) {
#     ...comparisonFields
#   }
#
#   rightComparison: hero(
#     episode: JEDI
#   ) {
#     ...comparisonFields
#   }
# }
#
# fragment comparisonFields on Character {
#   name
#   appearsIn
#   friends {
#     name
#   }
# }
```

Comment: Full documentation can be found at this link https://denisart.github.io/graphql-query/

Answer (score 0):

Another tool you could use is py-graphql-mapper.
Given a schema it will generate python code corresponding to GraphQL types, so if you would like to send a request containing a query, simply, the only thing you would need is to instantiate the corresponding python object, assign the arguments you need and send an HTTP post using the 'export_gql_source' property of the python class you used for the query.
More details here:

https://github.com/dapalex/py-graphql-mapper

Answer (score -5):

There is **no need to construct graphQL strings to inject variables**.

This is even **abusing graphQL** as **it was designed to separate query definition and variables** (arguments). It's safer, easier to validate etc.

**Just learn how to use `query variables` to pass arguments**. This is described in [docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/) and many tutorials. **You should know and use in practice this technique**. Trying to use string injections can at least prove lack of your knowledge.

If you aren't writting a graphql editor or other tool then you shouldn't use string operations at all. BTW even editor shouldn't operate on strings but on AST.

**It's rarely required to operate on strings in graphql**, f.e. to let user choose required answer (response part of query) elements/fragments.

### Update

Operating **using objects is more elastic/usable** - e.g. easily solves conditional problems: [How to conditionally include an argument in a GraphQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698051/6124657)

Comment: It would be extremely helpful for less experienced programmers to provide a working example of the best practices mentioned in your 'answer' instead of just sharing a single link (which not necessarily people will understand), and saying what NOT to do, and what to learn.

Comment: @lowercase00 Not working with python ... you have a working example in accepted answer ... this answer extends this, explains general graphql rules, why question (requirements), in general, is misleading ... passing variables is not 'best practice', it's a basic graphql knowledge ... look for more tutorials if still not understood or ask own, specific problem question, not about 'best practice' as asking for PERSONAL OPINIONS are off-topic on SO