# How to conditionally include a filtering argument in a GraphQL query?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I have the following GraphQL query (using Apollo Client JS):

```
query GetUsers($searchFilter: String) {
    users(
        first: 10,
        filter: { search: $searchFilter }
    ) {
        nodes {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

This works well when I pass in the `$searchFilter` argument. However, I want this `$searchFilter` argument to be **optional**. So when it's `null` it doesn't apply the filter.

This seems simple enough, but the API requires the `search` to be non-nullable. So passing in `filter: { search: null }` is not allowed.

I would like to achieve the following:

```
query GetUsers($searchFilter: String) {
    users(
        first: 10,
        filter: $searchFilter = null ? null : { search: $searchFilter }
    ) {
        nodes {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

How do I conditionally include the `filter` argument?

Comment: just pass (entire 'composed/prepared earlier') value or not (leave undefined) for `filter` variable ... no logic in graphql allowed (without directives, IMHO not suitable in this case)

Comment: @xadm What would be the syntax for that?

Comment: read `filter` arg type from server/api [this mutation] specs, pass object

Comment: `query GetUsers($filter: SomeFilterInputType) {  users(         first: 10, filter: $filter ) {...`, pass `filter: { search: 'sth'}`

Comment: @xadm That works, thanks! If you put that in an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just pass (entire 'composed/prepared earlier') value for `filter` (define at query) variable. Leaving this variable undefined makes it optional.

```
query GetUsers($filter: SomeFilterInputType) {
  users(
    first: 10, 
    filter: $filter ) {
```

pass value for `filter` in [query] variables:

```
{
  filter: { search: 'sth'}
}
```

**... where `SomeFilterInputType` is a [`users` query] arg type name, it can be read from API specs, available in graphiql/playground docs ... or server code/type defs**

It can be tested in graphiql/playground using QUERY VARIABLES.

**`variables` passed from JavaScript is an object with the same structure, easily created/modified conditionally.**

In this case `SomeFilterInputType` (no `!` mark after type name) means it (`filter` variable) can be nulled/undefined - **usually optional args are nullable** (not required). If some arg is required in API/BE specs then it must be required in client, too.

Comment: This helped me out a lot, thanks. Had no idea the `!` turned it into a non-nullable value.

Comment: I didn't know I can pass the whole filter block as a variable so this is amazing! Thank you.