# Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "" gatsby and graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I am getting the following error on a graphql query in a gatsby website where I am fetching data from the Strapi CMS.

**Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "" gatsby**

Here is the code:

```
export const Query = graphql`
 {
   source {
     people(where: {isSupport: true}) {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

With the above query, I am trying to fetch people that are part of the support team but I get this error **Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "isSupport"**

The above code works fine on the Graphql explorer. I then thought because the query is in a template string I should change my code as follows.

```
export const Query = graphql`
 {
   source {
     people(where: {${isSupport}: true}) {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

With the above code, I still could not get the desired results.

Looking closer into the graphql explorer I noticed that the `where` filter takes a JSON object so I converted my code as follows:

```
export const Query = graphql`
 {
   source {
     people(where: {"isSupport": true}) {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

With the above code, I still could not get the desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698051/6124657

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
export const Query = graphql`
 query ($isSupport: Boolean){
   source {
     people(where: {$isSupport: true}) {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

You are not defining the variable type in the query constructor (`$isSupport: String`).

In addition, I'm not familiar with `where` filter. The following should work too:

```
export const Query = graphql`
 query ($isSupport: Boolean){
   source (people: {isSupport: {eq: $isSupport}}) {
     people {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

The snippets above will filter all `sources` that have `people.isSupport` property equal to the value passed via context.

If you are not passing any value from context, check the value directly:

```
export const Query = graphql`
 {
   source (people: {isSupport: {eq: true}}) {
     people {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

Or applying `where` filter:

```
export const Query = graphql`
 {
   source {
     people(where: {isSupport: true}) {
       name
       photo {
         url
       }
       surname
       isSupport
     }
  }
`
```

Comment: simplest: pass filter/where value `where: {isSupport: true}` to $where

Comment: ... only the last will work :D other args changes doesnt change results
1st: variable for prop name not allowed; 2nd $isSupport should be boolean; 3rd $isSupport arg not used; 4th original question :D

Comment: `query ($where: SomeWhereInputType){ source { people(where: $where) {` and variables: `{ where: {isSupport: true} }`