# How to compare a variable in GraphQL query with a Value

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am trying to create a graphQL query in which i want to check if the variable by the name $Month is equal to the string "March". But i cant find a way to do it.

```
query MyQuery($userid : ID , $Month : String) {
  dbo_table(where: 
    { 
      userid: { _eq: $userid },
  
      _or : [ 
              { MonthCreated: { _eq : $Folder }},
              {  $Month  : { _eq : "March" }
            ]
    }
  )
```

```
    {  $Month  : { _eq : "March" }
```

The above approach is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: prepare and pass into query entire `where` object

Comment: @xadm Can you show an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698051/6124657 ?

Comment: You can also make a dynamic string query using string interpolation. Is that a bad idea for some reason @xadm?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky sure, can work but variables should be used instead ... string interpolation is a kind of abusing graphql ... query can be defined externally, in separate .gql file

Comment: Thanks. I imagined it was something like that @xadm

Answer (score 1):

In graphql you can send the needed variable to query handler and build your query using apollo, just like this...

```
query get_users_by_role ($role: String!){
  user(where: {role: {_eq: $role}}) {
    id
    username
  }
}
```

In the above example, I build a query for getting a list of users with the role name is matched with `role` variable that i will sent.

I send the query using applo as follows,

```
this.$apollo.query({
  query: gql`
    query get_users_by_role($role: String!) {
      user(where: { role: { _eq: $role } }) {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    role: "Admin",
  },
});
```

Ask me if you need further explanation.