# How to create/Fetch data dynamically by filters and order in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am creating a query in graphql + apollo client whose filters and orders can change depending on what the customer selects in the frontend. For example:

```
query (
        $orderPart: String!
        $wherePart: String!
        ) {
    getProductInfo(
        order {$orderPart}
        where {$wherePart}
    ) {
      productID
      description
      size
      model
      cathegoryNumber
    }
```

Where $orderPart will be equal to "description: DESC" or "productID: ASC" (depending what the customer selected in a momento or another). And $wherePart will be equal to "cathegoryNumber: {eq: 12}" or "productID: {eq: 111111}".

I need to pass the order/filter clause completely as a parameter.

But it doesn't work. Syntax is error "Syntax Error: Expected name, found $".

So my question is...

Is there any way to implement these dynamic filters/orders? How could this functionality be implemented? Is there any other way to implement this dynamic filters and orders?

Thanks.

Note:
In the official documentation, I found that only values can be passed as a parameters:

```
query (
        $orderValue: sortEnumType! = DESC
        $whereValue: String! = "description1"
        ) {
    getProductInfo(
        order {productID: $orderValue}
        where {description: {eq: $whereValue} }
    ) {
      productID
      description
      size
      model
      cathegoryNumber
    }
```

But that is not what I need because always filters/orders couldn't be changed. And they could be completely different each time (prodyuct:ASC) first time, (cathegoryNumber:DESC) second time, etc...

Comment: "doesn't work." is not useful. Please explain the issue. An error? unexpected response?

Comment: variables are not for string replacement - use `$where` and `$order` (read types from API docs) and pass objects as variables

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations - object passed

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I found a solution. Using apollo client and variables when the template is created:

```
let orderValue = 'order {productID: ASC}'; // built dynamically
let whereValue = 'description: {eq: "description1"}'; // built dynamically

document = gql`
query {
    getProductInfo(
        ${orderValue}
        ${whereValue}
    ) {
      productID
      description
      size
      model
      categoryNumber
    }
    `;
```

Comment: still, not the right solution .... (template literal+js variables) != graphql variables (https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698051/6124657