# Graphql set where parameter of type array to optional

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have this query

```
query restrictionsTrav($match: String, $offset: Int, $stateIds: [Int!]) {
  destinations_for_travel(limit: 100, offset: $offset, where: {city_name: {name: {_ilike: $match}, province_name: {state_Name: {id: {_in: $stateIds}}}}}) {
    is_Travel_Allowed
    city_status {
      name
      status
    }
    city_name{
      name
      province_name{
        name
        key
        state_Name{
          name
          long_name
          key
        }
      }
    }
    updated_at
  }
}
```

Basically, when I query it on Hasura, I have the following query variables: `match`, `offset`, and `stateIds`.
What I want to happen is that even if I leave `stateIds` empty, I will still see results that match `city_name` which is represented by the variable `match`. I tried removing the `!` from `stateIds` but I get an error:

```
Variable "$stateIds" of type "[Int]" used in position expecting type "[Int!]"
```

Is there a way wherein I can make the `stateIds` optional? With the query above, nothing displays if there are no values inside the array `stateIds`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698051/6124657

Comment: @xadm doesn't work. removing ! gives me an error in Hasura too

Comment: read entire answer ... pass `where` object as variable, not it's parts/fragments

Answer (score 1):

to make it optional you can pass a default value like so  `$stateIds: [Int!] = []`