# How to pass a variable as a value in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

It is possible to place any variable from a code in SQL queries, for example:

```
sqlalchemy_query= f'''
    order_id,
    order_sum
    from some_table_name
    where customer_id ={some_variable}
'''
```

As you can see everything is simple here: f-string, my variable in curly brackets. Nice, simple, and it works.

However, curly brackets in a similar JSON query for noSQL DB did not work for me. I was using elasticsearch Python Client with queries in JSON.

```
    {
       ...
       "customer_id": {some_variable_from_code}
       ...
    }
```

*So how can I pass variables inside JSON strings in Python?*

Is there any character I need to escape, [like in .NET](https://forums.asp.net/t/2102832.aspx?How%20to%20pass%20a%20simple%20variables%20inside%20a%20JSON%20string%20)?

Comment: _JSON query for noSQL DB_ - Can you tell us what API you are using? It may do the serialization for you. Otherwise, stick with python data structures and use `json.dumps` to do the serialization.

Comment: @tdelaney I was using elasticsearch Python Client. It allows using queries in JSON.

Comment: elasticsearch generally does the serialization for you. Just stick with python data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your query formatted as an f string contains literal curly braces you would need to double the curly braces in this case:

```
some_variable_from_code = "foo"
query_string = f"""{{"customer_id": {some_variable_from_code}}}"""
print(query_string)
```

Results in:

```
{"customer_id": foo}
```

Comment: But it seems like you are trying to build JSON here which is a bad idea. That's what `json.dumps` is for. `some_variable_from_code` could well have characters that would not be legal in JSON. A double quote for example. Of if its a boolean, "True" instead of "true".

Comment: Just trying to meet the OP where they are at, which is trying to parse a string to pass as a query, and getting stuck on a string formatting error. As you noted previously this isn't really about JSON, they were just trying to overcome a string formatting problem. In my programming journey I've gotten stuck by trying to prematurely optimize for 'best practice', when realistically at this stage OP is just looking for something that functions.

Comment: This answer was upvoted and accepted even though it doesn't answer the real question _Is there any character I need to escape_. Its not the right way to do it.

Comment: @t Thanks everyone. This answer is exactly what I was looking for. My apologies if anything wasn't clear.


I will clarify here that I need to use a variable in a JSON query for ElasticSearch. In short, I was connecting to ES using Python and querying it using JSON queries. Because I wanted to automate my work for future use, I needed to pass a variable in queries, I would be able to  re run everything without changing every query one by one.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me to assemble GraphQL queries.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no JSON here. JavaScript Object Notation is a serialized representation of data. Once you've deserialized it into python, its not JSON. When you did `{some_variable_from_code}` that's a python set with a single value. You could just do

```
{
    "customer_id": some_variable_from_code
}
```

After you've created the python dict, its serialzied to JSON for the call, but that happens under the covers.